# Domain name changes to IP address

Tags: apache2, url

On my VPS I created a website in Ubuntu 16.04. In the DNS the IP address is connected to my domain name.
When I enter the domain name in the address bar in the browser, the domain name changed to the IP address. The website will be shown.

How do I setup virtual hosts so that the domain name remains in the address bar?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin admin@domain.nl
  DocumentRoot /var/www/www.domain.nl/public_html
  ServerAlias www.domain.nl
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin admin@domain.nl
  DocumentRoot /var/www/www.domain.nl/public_html
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /usr/share/ca-certificates/domain.nl/domain.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/share/ca-certificates/domain.nl/domain.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/share/ca-certificates/domain.nl/DigiCertCA.crt
  ServerName domain.nl
  ServerAlias www.domain.nl

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.nl [OR]
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.nl
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

The remarks at the end are for enabling the SSL certificate, but I have to do that after this problem is solved.

Kind regards,
Guido

Comment: Have you configured DNS correctly?

Comment: Do you use any .htaccess? Can we see your DNS configuration?